# Build bundle.js in create-react-app application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

Made a project. Now we need to collect everything in one `bundle.js`, and not in the way `create-react-app` does.

Executed the `eject` command, configs appeared. But how do i get `bundle.js`?

It is important that everything that is in the project (styles, pictures, etc.) be gathered into one file.

### ## My Solution

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: "widget.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|woff(2)?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            publicPath: 'img',
                            outputPath: 'img',
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                warnings: false,
                parse: {},
                compress: {},
                mangle: true,
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                },
                toplevel: false,
                nameCache: null,
                ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: false,
            },
        })],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: It's unclear. Did you try to run `npm run build`? This is how it's built. No ejection needed. How do you use that styles and images? If you don't `import` them, you won't be able to bundle them. If you import them, they should be already in a bundle.

Comment: @estus Yes, i tried to run `npm run build` command, but i get `chunk` files, static folder e.t.c. But i need one file. All styles, images imported.

Comment: Static files won't become JS bundle by magic. You need to import them. And that's questionable move any way because it's not efficient.

Comment: @estus now all `css` compiled in one `chunk.css` file. But this files i use in imports into js. why?I import all files: css, images.

Comment: Likely because it was configured like that, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L579-L584 .  You can check all chunk-related webpack options and plugins and disable them where needed. I can't suggest anything more specific, I personally never did that because this is a shot in the foot that will hurt the app.

Comment: @estus in my case i need exactly bundle file. Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? if you did please share!

Comment: @IamMashed Yes. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ejecting is a real bad solution, instead use rewire `npm install react-app-rewired` and add a customized build script.

please checkout my answer here
[How to build a production version of React without minification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification/55165586#55165586)