# How to build a production version of React without minification?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, minify, create-react-app, react-scripts

### Background

I've been following more or less [the official guide to setup a local dev environment with react](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) and it seems to use `create-react-app`, which sets up really a lot.

Now, if I run `npm run build` I get a minified version of everything in the `build` folder.
If I, however, run `npm start` the version NodeJS serves does not seem to have any modifications. But I cannot see these files.

### Question

So either:

- Can I access the files generated by `npm start` somewhere? As these seem to be unmodified. (`build` is never modified there)
- Or can I somehow run `npm run build`, so it does a "development" build with unminimized files?

### Tries

My aim is just **to get access to an unminimized version of react scripts**.

As for the last question I've tried [some parameters and enironmental variables as suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092940/npm-run-build-always-builds-production-and-never-development), but as you can see, it failed:

```
$ NODE_ENV=dev npm run build --dev --configuration=dev

> example-project@0.1.0 build [...]
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
[...]
```

### System

My `package.json` has the default scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

---

**Note:** Please do not ask why I am doing it or try to convince me that it is bad. There are many reasons why I'd maybe want this, e.g. debugging or [this specific use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160698/how-to-use-react-without-unsafe-inline-javascript-css-code).

Comment: BTW, as it seems to be a very hard thing, I've [asked the `create-react-app` devs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6643), whether this may be implemented by default in their scripts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To change the webpack config and build scripts you have either to eject from create-react-app (i would not recommend this step, as it breaks future compatibility) or use tools like rewire to override some settings

Take a look at this.
https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

I personally used just rewire

```
npm i rewire --save-dev
```

Here is a sample config i created for one of my projects in the past and it worked pretty good!

1. Create `build.js`
2. Change your package.json so that it runs build.js

**build.js**

```
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
const config = defaults.__get__('config');

// Consolidate chunk files instead
config.optimization.splitChunks = {
  cacheGroups: {
    default: false,
  },
};
// Move runtime into bundle instead of separate file
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;

// JS
config.output.filename = '[name].js';
// CSS. "5" is MiniCssPlugin
config.plugins[5].options.filename = '[name].css';
config.plugins[5].options.publicPath = '../';
```

Then in my package.json i changed the npm script links like this
(node build which will run the build.js script)

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node build && gulp",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

So if you really want to eject from create-react-app, all you have to do is to run

```
npm run-script eject
```

Then you will get a new folder with all configs used by create-react-app

But as i said before, there is no reason why not to use rewire and just override the config instead of ejecting.

Comment: This info got me on the warpath thanks. I switched to `react-app-rewired`. Followed steps 1-3 to `config-overrides.js`, and used spread operators to modify the default webpack config.

Comment: I got this working using the above script plus:

`config.optimization.minimize = false;`

Comment: In my case the minifier was index 4.. rather than using `config.plugsin[5]` you're best of with something like:  `const minifier = config.plugins.find((plugin) => plugin.constructor.name === "MiniCssExtractPlugin");` to avoid errors when the create react app build script is altered.

Comment: ^ That returns null, when I do it - you sure you got the name right, @uɥƃnɐʌuop ? `const minifier = config.plugins.find((plugin) => plugin.constructor.name === "MiniCssExtractPlugin");`

Comment: @dylanh724, no I can't be sure what it usually is, I just know that was working when I left the comment. It's probably config specific or may have changed since then. I do recall I logged out each plugin's constructor.name in order to obtain `MiniCssExtractPlugin`

Comment: should be noted: [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) is now "lightly maintained" by the community.

Comment: I used the instanceof operstor to find my plugin:  
    `const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find( plugin => plugin instanceof MiniCssExtractPlugin)`.  Of course you need to import the plugin before:     `const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')`

Answer (score 15):

I wanted the unobfuscated code of a React app - mostly of curiosity, I had the source - while having the job of rewriting it in Angular (producing a far more maintainable app 5% of the size and 1% dependencies).

I've never used React but discovered by modifying the file

> <base_path>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js

and replacing the large optimization config item, under module.exports, with the following...

```
module.exports = {...

    optimization: {
            minimize: false,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                name: true
            },
            runtimeChunk: true
        },
```

**npm run build** built unobfuscated, readable code that ran as expected, using no other modifications. Used Gitbash only with the commands *npm install*, *npm run build* and *npm start*  - Just thought someone may find that useful.

I don't recommend this because the code you want is still wrapped in a webpack eval mess.  It's easier to pick the useful bits from the source or just rebuild the app.  At best, I got to see what a cluster react and webpack is.

Comment: I am running VS2019 and the above did not work for me. There is no webpack.config.prod.js file only webpack.config.js. I did find the 'optimization' key in webpack.config.js and replaced it with the above but it still published minified output. Thx anyway!

Comment: Using that one still works for me.  Perhaps stash the config file and, if it builds, there's more than one config.  Also, I'm building with gitbash npm commands only.

Comment: thanks for digging this up! absurd that the library won't just let you override this easily

Comment: @KellyCode Thank you, this is an absolute lifesaver - never mind whether this is 'recommended' or not, or whether the webpack mess is still there, it simply allows me to get a clue as to where my code is going wrong ... I also looked at a Github issue "Question: Can I make non-minified build" (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3403), and their blunt answer was simply "it will not be supported" ... the difference between your response and theirs is, one is helpful, and the other totally not :)

Comment: @KaiserShahid I completely agree, there's a Github issue about this with the CRA team/project ("Question: Can I make non-minified build" (github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3403) but the response is "we're not going to support it" and that's it ... really no idea why something as simple as this should be a big deal? In the meantime I just use KellyCode's hack and that works fine for me :)

Comment: On my copy, I had to change node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js, specifically I changed `minimize: isEnvProduction` on line 259 of the `optimization` section to `minimize: false`, and `react-scripts build` obeyed.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you see the source files? Here is what I would try:

1. Start your react app with `npm run start`
2. Open your browser to `http://localhost:3000`
3. Open *Developer tools and inspect the created chunked bundles by the webpack-dev server*. In Chrome on a mac, you can do the following: `cmd+option+j` will open developer tools. Then click the **sources** tab: within this tab you will s*ee the bundles created by react's build configuration*. Now the output of these bundles might not be pretty but it's all there.

Alternatively, all your application's build configuration settings are contained within your `webpack.config.js` file even when you use `create-react-app`. As this *configuration is just encapsulated within the `react-scripts` node module*. So maybe you could try editing this file directly, without ejecting: `<base_path>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`. Although you need to be careful as to not break an existing configuration setting. You probably want to mess with the `source-map` settings for production builds. At least this way if you ruin this file you can always just remove and reinstall `react-scripts` and be back to your initial configuration. This will also allow you to play around with your customizations in 'semi-safe' sandboxed environment. Remember, there is no magic that `create-react-app` is providing rather it's just making *useful defaults for your build configuration.*

Lastly, as @xzesstence pointed out you can try out the [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) module.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: While all you suggest is likely technically possible, it seems to be a big workaround with much potential to break when I either update npm modules or so. And it's really not using the tools (npm, etc.) in the way they are designed/intended to.
Exporting via the browser is also ugly as I e.g. want all files in a directory, but in the browser I can AFAIK only open single files and could possibly manually copy/paste them, but no... this does never fit in a developer's workflow. (especially as I need to do this often!)

Comment: then you should try the rewire way and this is no workaround and it breaks nothing.. you literally just add a build.js like the one i posted and then you modify the config as you need.. you can update dependencies without any limitations and you will never loose your config.

first i was thinking the same like you, why is this so complicated but it is really simple and there are logical reasons why they added default configs as dependencies. its a great solution overall i really can recommend. i used it several times in a huge production environment
just give it a try and see what you get

Comment: Not sure I agree, but I also think this is a personal preference for each developer.  There is no exporting to the browser you're simply using using developer tools the way they were meant to be used for the first option. This is the point of developer tools as it's part of every frontend developer day to day and dev tools are a fantastic tool set. The second option is modifying the build config within your webpack.config.js to get the recommended build directory files. Although you can for sure break a module it's a simply install away from being back to normal

Comment: It also depends on how you want to use create-react-app as it's meant to provide good defaults that fit most use cases but not individual customizations. There is no magic behind create-react-app it simply provides a useful project structure and good defaults for a build config. It kind of obfuscates the details of this which is good/bad but if you weren't using create-react-app you would have to set up these details. As for the library option I see your point and I am not arguing against it as personally I like to have granular control and would provide my own build configs

Comment: But using the library adds an additional layer of complexity for new team members to learn so you have to weigh that against just having a working config. But in the end it's a personal preference and there are no wrong options as long as everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

The files are kept in the server process memory and not written to disk, unless you eject the scripts (or if it is possible to use a tool like 'rewire') and modify them to write it to disk using the `writeToDisk` option as described in [the webpack DevServer docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-).

You can however get the actual file list/links by navigating to the `webpack-dev-server` endpoint under the server.

For instance if using the default url at localhost:3000 then use the following url to see all files on the server:

`http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server`

But what you really need is only the index.html (which is in general just a stub that loads the JS files) and the 3 following JS files which appear to be consistent on all create-react-app installments, along with their respective source map files.

1. main.chunk.js
2. bundle.js
3. vendors~main.chunk.js

You can just right click on the links on the page and save them, or you can navigate direct the link or get them from the Chrome Dev Tools "sources" tab.

Note that in general for code changes only the main.chunk.js file is updated, so for the average code change you might just fetch the updated main.chunk.js and main.chunk.js.map files.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's way too late to answer this, but try this `npm i -D cra-build-watch`.

I feel this library is underrated but it just watch the changes in react app and does not re-build the whole package again and again.

Although rewiring helps in making the build by not minifying it, however, still it goes through the whole process of building again and again.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a whole day on this problem, I could not find a way to get the none-minified version of the production code,

what I did was: open the dev tools on chrome, navigate to the sources tab; now  find the javascript file (in create-react-app it is usually in static > js > main.js)

when the javascript file is visible, at the bottom left of the screen a pair of curly braces appear (look at the image):

[screenshot of the dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4ine.jpg)

when you click on the curly braces, it beautifies the code, and then you can add breakpoints to the code (click on the number on the line ) and refresh the page to start the debugger, it is not convenient to deal with that code, but for now that is what worked for me.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to configure this from the webpack.config.js in the /react-scripts NPM package, you can configure this directly in your craco.config.js file, this will override the webpack.config.js configuration. You can do it as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
     configure: {
      optimization: {
        minimize: false
      },
    },
} ...;
```