# react-scripts build an unminified version

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

How do can you get the "build": "react-scripts build" in a package.json to build an unminified version of the code.

I have looked at the answers in this post but they are all too complicated:

[How to build a production version of React without minification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification)

I can see in node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js that the build is set by this code:

```
const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development'
const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
```

if I added a build-dev in the package.json, how would I make webpackEnv 'development'?

Answer (score 0):

Hack valid (at least used) for React 17.0.2 & Co.

Open the file
`node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js`

Locate the lines saying

```
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

Change to

```
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

Locate the line saying

```
const config = configFactory('production');
```

Change to

```
const config = configFactory('development');
```

If the error is disturbing your env, then comment out

```
  printFileSizesAfterBuild(
    stats,
    previousFileSizes,
    paths.appBuild,
    WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE,
    WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE
  );
```

to

```
  /*
  printFileSizesAfterBuild(
    stats,
    previousFileSizes,
    paths.appBuild,
    WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE,
    WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE
  );
  */
```

Then (adjust the file copying to your local environment):

```
npm run build
scp -r build/* dist/* target:/webroot
```

Good luck.